# Why 'hippo-paw-tamus?'

Tags: pronunciation, latin, greek

The ruminations of an idle mind:

Several English words such as *potion*, *potable*, *potables*, *poison*, derive from the Latin root *potare*, *poto* "to drink". In all cases these words are pronounced with a long 'o' as in 'oh'.

The noble *hippopotamus*, according to [OED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hippopotamus):

> derives from Late Latin *hippopotamus*, from Greek *hippopotamus* "riverhorse," an irregular formation from earlier *ho hippos potamios* "the horse of the river", from *hippos* "horse" (see equine) + adjective from *potamos* "river, rushing water"

In turn, the word element *potamos-* is [described](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=potamo-&allowed_in_frame=0):

> word-forming element meaning "river," from comb. form of Greek potamos "river," perhaps literally "rushing water," from PIE *pet- "to rush, to fly" (see petition).

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a resource that indicates how *potamos-* is pronounced in Greek and Latin. My reasoning is that, like the root *potare*, the element is pronounced with a long 'o'. However the OED excerpt above suggests the pronunciation might also be "*pet*-amos".

This raises two questions:

1. How is *potamos-* pronounced in Greek, and does it have any relation to the Latin roots *potare* and *poto*?
2. Where does the "paw" in "hippo-*paw*-tamus" come from? It seems to me that in order to be consistent with other English words, which preserve the *poh* sound, the pronunciation ought to be "hippo-*poh*-tamus" or possibly "hippo-*pet*-amus", and yet this clearly isn't the case.

I realize this subject is more than a little obscure, but any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Some people pronounce the words *cot* and *caught* differently; *hippopotamus* has the vowel of *cot*, but the spelling *aw* suggests the vowel of *caught*.

Comment: @Nothingatall: You're saying that some people pronounce "cot" like "coat"?

Comment: @Nothing at all -- Regardless of the "cot"/"caught" dilemma, I believe the OP is asking why the second O in "hippopotamus" isn't pronounced exactly the same as the first O, which admittedly, I've never heard.  Phonetically, they should be pronounced the same.  Based on Latin, they should be pronounced the same.  They're not pronounced the same, though.  So It's a fair question, one for which I haven't the foggiest.

Comment: @COTO No. *Cot*, *coat*, and *caught* all sound distinct for these people (and that includes me).

Comment: "poison" doesn't have long "o." As for "hippopotamus," the vowel is short because it's stressed and in the third-to-last syllable. This is a general thing: compare the pronunciation of "o" in "verbose" and "verbosity." It has little to do with the vowel length in Greek or Latin.

Comment: @sumelic - "Poison" doesn't have a long O because the first is involved in a diphthong and the second would require a silent E after N to make it long.  Generally, in English, what tells someone that a vowel is long mid sentence is if it's followed by a single consonant, whereas a double consonant makes it short.  I know of no such rule in phonetics wherein a third to the last syllable, when stressed, gets a short vowel.  What about words like "imposingly," "supposedly," "notarize," and the like?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: It's a general rule, but it's not the only rule. It has a limited scope (I don't remember exactly what it is) and there are many other rules that can override it. And there are also words that are just exceptions. Wikipedia has an article on it: [trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: e.g. "imposingly" and "supposedly" are outside of the scope of the trisyllabic laxing rule because they are formed with the native English suffix "-ly." I don't know about "notarize," but it's possible that words suffixed with "-ize" are also generally immune.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the second <o> precedes the sound of the <a>, so saying it fast transfers the <a> sound to the second <o> as well

Comment: In essence, people are lazy. It takes more effort to maintain the mouth shape for the second "poe" sound, then switch quickly to the mouth shape needed for "tomus", than it does to let it slide into "pah" and then ease into "tomus".

Comment: Also, compare the second <o> in hippo**pot**amus to the word **pot**, which is pronounced as **cot**

Comment: @AeonAkechi What do you mean by "**Some** people pronounce the words *cot* and *caught* differently"?  Doesn't **everyone** (who's a native English speaker) pronounce them differently?

Comment: @RonJohn No, many Americans pronounce them both with the same sound as 'father'.

Comment: @AeonAkechi where?

Comment: @RonJohn I'm not sure on the exact regions, but look up the cot-caught merger and the father-bother merger. http://dialectblog.com/2011/03/08/the-cot-caught-merger/

Comment: @AeonAkechi well, I've certainly never heard them pronounced them the same.  To be honest, though, "cot" isn't a word I hear used very often.

Comment: @RonJohn There's evidence OP here would pronounce them the same way right in the title, from how they spell out hippopotamus (/hɪpəpɒtəməs/ to me) as 'hippo-paw-tamus' (which to me would suggest /hɪpəpɔːtəməs/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latin *potare* "drink" is from a Proto-Indo-European root **p(e)h3-* meaning "drink" (De Vaan), so it is not related to the root **pet-* "to rush" that you mentioned for *potamos*.

The Greek omikron in ποτᾰμός (potamos) is short and would be pronounced short in Latin. The ō in Latin *pōtare*, however, is long, so the two o's are pronounced differently in Latin.

As to you *paw*, I don't recognise that pronunciation. The Oxford English Dictionary (2nd edition) has /pɒ/ for the *-po-* in *-potamus*, which sounds just like the *po-* in the word *pot*. The first *-po-* is pronounced /pəʊ/ or /pə/.

It should be noted that any Proto-Indo-European root mentioned, such as **pet-*, is not to be interpreted as a guide for pronunciation; pronunciation is extremely likely to have changed between Proto-Indo-European (presumably spoken thousands of years ago) and modern English.

Comment: The pronunciation of the stressed syllable as *-paw-* sounds a bit like Brooklynese to me.

Comment: @Brian: it's more like a traditional Boston accent, where *party* is pronounced like *potty*, and *potty* like *paw-tee*.

Comment: Hence, in short, you're saying that the "pot" in "hippopotamus" isn't related to the Latin roots _potare_ and _poto_, and that what started out as "hippopetamus" due to the _*pet-_ in _potamus_ spuriously changed to "hippopotamus" over the centuries. Is that accurate?

Comment: @COTO: Yes, except that hypothetical *\*pet-* changed into *pot-* very, very long ago, probably before writing existed, and before the earliest Greek inscriptions. This isn't about centuries, it's about millennia. The word for "river" in Greek was always *potamos*, as far as we can tell from Greek writings. And the word *hippopotamos* was formed (much?) later than *potamos*. So there was certainly never a spelling *hippopetamus*.